# moodle 3.6 How to get the progress of a learner using web service functions

Tags: php, laravel, moodle, moodle-api

Can we get the course progress of a learner such as (30% or 60% completed) for a specific course in `Moodle 3.6`

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach that should work:

- Turn on completion tracking in the course settings
- Setup activity completion for the activities in the course that should be included in the progress calculation
- Use the  `core_completion_get_activities_completion_status` WS function to get the completion status of each activity. This leverages the core `get_activities_completion_status` function to return an array including each activity and its completion status.
- Traverse the returned array to calculate progress based on completed activities.

Your calculated result should match the progress % reported for each course in the dashboard that appears when using Boost and many other themes.

One case where this may not return what you expect (whether using web services or in core Moodle completion/progress reporting) is if your course includes activities like SCORM packages where progress within the activity can be tracked.

For example, if your course includes 5 SCORM activities/packages, and each one is 50% complete, but the activity completion rules for each SCORM activity require a "completed" or "passed" status for the package, course progress will likely display as 0% ( 0 out of 5) in Moodle or in the data returned by the WS function because all packages are still in progress. Calculating progress using progress within an activity can be done but usually requires a bit of customization to return what you expect.

Good luck with it!